# Separates Points Property of Norm defined by Integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{C}[0,1] $ be the space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$ and define 
$$  \| f \|_1 = \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)| \ dx \quad \text{and} \quad \| f \|_0 = \int_{0}^{1} x |f(x)| \ dx.  $$
Assume that $ \| \cdot \|_1 $ is a norm on $ \mathcal{C}[0,1] $. I was having a difficult time showing the property that $ \|  f \|_0 = 0  \implies f \equiv 0$. I can't help but feel there must be a slick way to do it since I didn't use the first norm  $ \| \cdot \|_1 $ . Here is my proof (?) of the "separates points" property of a norm for $ \|  \cdot \|_0 $ :

Suppose $ f \not\equiv 0$. Using integration by parts, we set $ u = x $ and $dv = |f(x)| \ dx $. 
Then,
$
 \int_{0}^{1} x |f(x)| \ dx =\left[ x \cdot  \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dt \right]_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dt \ dx     
= \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| \ dt -   \int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dt \ dx.
$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$ v(x) = \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dt, \quad \text{with} \ x \in [0,1] . $$

Observe that for all $x \in [0,1]$, $$  v(x) = \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dt  \leq  \int_{0}^{1} | f(t) | \ dt = M,  $$
which follows from the fact that our function is positive. Now, since we're assuming $ f(t) $ is not $0$, $ M > 0$. And as $v(0) = 0 $, the continuous function $ v(x) $ is ``strictly bounded above" by $ M$.   Hence,

$$  \int_{0}^{1} v(x) \ dx <  \int_{0}^{1} M \ dx \iff  \int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dt \ dx < \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} | f(t) | \ dt \ dx, $$ where the inequality here is strict. It follows that

$ \|f \|_0 = \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| \ dt -   \int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dt \ dx > \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| \ dt - \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| \ dt \ dx = 0. $

We conclude $ f \not\equiv 0 \implies \|f \|_0 > 0 $.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, this is a slick way using the first norm:

Since $\| \cdot \|_1 $ is a norm, for a continuous function $g $ we have $ \int^1_0 |g(x)| dx =0 $ if and only if $g = 0 $ identically.

If $f$ is continuous then so is $xf(x)$ so then assume $ 0 = \int^1_0 x |f(x) | dx = \int^1_0 |x f(x) | dx.$ Then by the above result, $xf(x)=0$ identically. Thus, we already have $f(x)=0 $ on $(0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous, we must also have $f(0)=0 $ so $f=0$ identically, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is a $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\ne 0$. By continuity there exists $\epsilon>0$ so that $x|f(x)|>0$   for all $x\in (-\epsilon+ x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$. Using the compactness of the closed interval $K=[-\frac \epsilon 2+x_0,x_0+\frac \epsilon 2]$ there is a minimum $m>0$ for $x|f(x)|$ in $K$. It follows that $m\cdot \epsilon\leq \int_K x|f(x)|dx\leq \int_0^1 x|f(x)|dx. $